# Glassfish v2 alternatedocroot - will DAS sync it?

Tags: java, glassfish, alternate

Using
Sun Glassfish Enterprise server v2.1.1

I am using "alternatedocroot" via sun-web.xml for my web application to abstract out static content from actual deploy-able code (EAR/WAR)

What I have is a cluster of two server instances distributed across two physical hosts - HOST1 and HOST2. "alternatedocroot" points to /data/static-content/ on both HOST1 and HOST2.
Would DAS (Domain application server )take care of syncing /data/static-content between HOST1 and HOST2 if I use syncinstances=true option while starting up the cluster?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No DAS will not sync anything that is non-standard.